# Generation code from xml layout

Tags: android, xml

For example, I have some layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test">
        </TextView>    
</LinearLayout>
```

I want generate code from layout:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
layout.setLayoutParams(lp);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

TextView textview = new TextView(context);
lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layout.setLayoutParams(lp);
textview.setText("test");
layout.addView(textview);
```

Can anybody know tools for this?

Comment: Do you want to use your layout in your Activity code? Or something else?

Comment: @Zorn, yes, I want to use in Activity code. Sometimes I don't want create xml file and inflate it, because this xml can simple and/or xmls can be very much and I don't want trash my res\layout folder.